# How to add LCOV_EXCL_LINE marker for code coverage in C or C++ code?

Tags: lcov

I tried two ways to add `LCOV_EXCL_LINE` in my code.

1. I add it as comment, compile and generate `lcov` report but `lcov` binary takes it as a comment and showing the coverage of excluded line.
   [Image showing coverage of excluded line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7FeZ.png):
   [image: Image showing coverage of excluded line]
2. After compilation and execution I add `LCOV_EXCL_LINE` before running `lcov` and `genhtml` binaries but it results in misalignment after first exclusion.
   [Image showing misalignment coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hrmC.png):
   [image: Image showing misalignment coverage]

Comment: I am taking coverage of compiler front end source code, their are multiple directories and files. For other references I just wrote a code(images attached) and did exactly the same thing what I did in my source code. I guess that is explainable, I am not getting how to add this marker. Did u know that ?

Answer (score 6):

You add the comment in the line you want excluded. Not in the line before that you want excluded.

Answer (score -1):

As [1737973](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1737973/1737973) said, you should do something like:

```
printf("* ")  // LCOV_EXCL_LINE
printf("\n")  // LCOV_EXCL_LINE
```